# I have a code to put the whole content of different multiple .txt files into Excel 2010, but needs some changes

Tags: excel, text, import

Is there any way I can put the whole content of different multiple .txt files (practically the content of all .txt file in one folder) into Excel 2010? I need one cell (A1) to be the name of the file, and the other cell (A2) to be the whole content of that .txt file. The same goes for the other .txt files, i.e. B1-B2, C1-C2, etc.

I have this code:

```
Sub test() 
    Dim myDir As String, fn As String, ff As Integer, txt As String 
    Dim delim As String, n As Long, b(), flg As Boolean, x 
    myDir = "c:\test" '<- change to actual folder path
    delim = vbTab '<- delimiter (assuming Tab delimited)
    Redim b(1 To Rows.Count, 1 To 1) 
    fn = Dir(myDir & "\*.txt") 
    Do While fn <> "" 
        ff = FreeFile 
        Open myDir & "\" & fn For Input As #ff 
        Do While Not EOF(ff) 
            Line Input #ff, txt 
            x = Split(txt, delim) 
            If Not flg Then 
                n = n + 1 : b(n,1) = fn 
            End If 
            If UBound(x) > 0 Then 
                n = n + 1 
                b(n,1) = x(1) 
            End If 
            flg = True 
        Loop 
        Close #ff 
        flg = False 
        fn = Dir() 
    Loop 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1").Resize(n).Value = b 
End Sub
```

But the thing with this code is that it imports only the filenames, but not the content, and I suppose that this is due to the fact the above code uses "delim = vbTab" and I don't have any delimiter in the content of the files. I want the whole content of one file to be imported into one cell.

Comment: Second time you asked the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402347/put-the-content-of-multiple-txt-files-into-excel-2010) and code is copy from another forum. What you need is to hire a (vba) programmer or if you want to become one yourself to put a bit more effort in yourself before asking.

Comment: I know, but I already found another easier code to use, and I needed just a litle help to modify it. So I don't see why should I hire a VBA programmer, for such a simple fix, that this guys made it happen... Now the code is working as it should, and I'm so grateful to these guys for the help.

Comment: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileSystemObject`  (part of Microsoft Scripting Runtime) offers a good file handling alternative.

Here's a quick outline that utilises this module.

Note:

1. It utilises early binding, therefore requires a reference to the Scripting Runtime.  Can easily be altered to late binding if you prefer.
2. For clarity I have ommitted error handling and various speed optimisations.  Whether it's safe enough or fast enough will depend on your intended use and number and size of files.

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim txt As TextStream
    Dim pth As String
    Dim fl As File
    Dim str As String
    Dim cl As Range

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    pth = "C:\Test"
    Set cl = [A1]
    For Each fl In fso.GetFolder(pth).Files
        If StrComp(Right(fl.Name, 4), ".txt", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile(fl.Path, ForReading)
            cl = fl.Name
            str = txt.ReadAll

            ' option: use this loop to split long files into multiple cells
            Do While Len(str) > 32767
                cl.Offset(0, 1) = Left(str, 32767)
                Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 1)
                str = Mid(str, 32768)
            Loop

            cl.Offset(0, 1) = str
            Set cl = cl.EntireRow.Cells(2, 1)
            txt.Close
        End If
    Next

    Set txt = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same approach you're using, but I do it this way:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportManyTXTIntoColumns()
'Summary:   From a specific folder, import TXT files 1 file per column
Dim fPath As String, fTXT As String
Dim wsTrgt As Worksheet, NC As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\2010\"                      'path to files
Set wsTrgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add    'new sheet for incoming data
NC = 1                                  'first column for data

fTXT = Dir(fPath & "*.txt")             'get first filename

    Do While Len(fTXT) > 0              'process one at a time
                                        'open the file in Excel
        Workbooks.OpenText fPath & fTXT, Origin:=437
                                        'put the filename in the target column
        wsTrgt.Cells(1, NC) = ActiveSheet.Name
                                        'copy column A to new sheet
        Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlConstants).Copy wsTrgt.Cells(2, NC)

        ActiveWorkbook.Close False      'close the source file
        NC = NC + 1                     'next column
        fTXT = Dir                      'next file
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```