# Importing multiple text files to Excel based on specific characters in the data, and adding additional data when importing

Tags: excel, import, vba

I've found an answer to import lines of data from numerous text files into an Excel sheet (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941605/1892030 answered by Chris Neilsen). However I would like to also do the following:

1. There is garbage data before and after the useful data I want to import. The lines of data I want to import all start with an asterix (*).
2. The data is comma delimited and must be parsed that way when imported into Excel. This I could change by editing the parse code in the above answer.
3. At the end of each line that is imported, I want to add an additional item of data which is the name of the text file where the data was imported from (name of file only, without file extension).

The answer from Chris refered to above works real well so I would like to edit the code to allow for my additional requirements under points 1 and 3 above - but don't know how. For completeness I copy the code from the earlier answer below. Many thanks.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\#test")

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files

        ' Open the file
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream

            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

            ' Parse the line into comma delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, ",")

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
            Next

            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)

        Loop

        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close

    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it all for you (I expect the file name will need tidying up to fit the format you want) but drop this code in and it will get you started...

```
    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream

        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Process lines which don't begin with Asterisk (*)
        If Left(TextLine,1)<>"*" Then 

            ' This crudely appends the filename as if it were a column in the source file
            TextLine = TextLine + "," + file.Name

            ' Parse the line into comma delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, ",")

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
            Next

            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Works great, but had to change If Left(TextLine,1)<>"*" Then to = *. Thanks a lot for the help.